# How to search for an element in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, find

i have a code like this....

```
std::vector<string>::iterator p;
p =  find(v.begin(),v.end(),"asdasda"); 
cout << *p << endl;
```

if "asdasda" is not a part  of the vector, p points to some garbage and cout gives a seg fault. what should be the if statement that would make the cout execute onlyif "asdasda" was found?
and also the position of "asdasda" in v.. like if we had earlier declared v[3] as "asdasda",
then how can i know from the find that v[3] is "asdasda"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`p` doesn't point to "garbage", it simply becomes `v.end()` when the content is not found.

```
if (p != v.end()) {
   std::cout << "v[" << (p - v.begin()) << "] = ";
   std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: how to find the position of "asdasda" in v.. like if we had earlier declared v[3] as "asdasda", then how can i know from the find that v[3] is "asdasda"?

Answer (score 4):

If `std::find` doesn't find anything, the iterator is set to `v.end()` in this case.

```
if ( p != v.end() )
{
    // iterator is good
}
```

Also note the general case of `std::find`.

Here's a typical definition of it:

```
namespace std {
  template <class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find(InputIterator start, 
                     InputIterator finish,
                     const T& value);
}
```

In case `std::find` fails, it will return the `finish` iterator because the search is `[start, finish)` and includes `start` but excludes `finish`.

Answer (score 1):

Find returns the end iterator if it doesn't find the value you search.
You can avoid your error by adding `if (p != v.end())` right before your display line.

Comment: how to find the position of "asdasda" in v.. like if we had earlier declared v[3] as "asdasda", then how can i know from the find that v[3] is "asdasda"?

Comment: `p - v.start()`, if `p != v.end()`.